# ASP.NET MVC5 , Url parameter And Get method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does using RouteData.Values is the right way to get the Url parameter from GET method?
for example the url : http://www.mywebsite.com/Product/Search/Apple
In the controller, the method parameter won't bind the url parameter as POST method do.
Or something i can do, so whether POST or GET, the parameter will auto bind to method paramether?

The Route:

```
 context.MapRoute(
      "Product_Search",
      "{controller}/{action}/{Keyword}",
      new { controller = "Product", action = "Search", Keyword = "" }
 );
```

The Controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search(string keyword) //< the keyword here is null
    {    
        string keyword = Convert.ToString(RouteData.Values["SearchText"]); //<keyword here is fine = 'Apple'.
       // Do search 

        return View("SearchResult", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: *RouteData.Values["SearchText"]*??? instead of *SearchText* you have to use on of *controller*, *action* or *Keyword*

Comment: The code you have shown works fine and the parameter `string keyword` will be correctly bound. Best guess is this is not you only route (and you still have the Default route (with `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"`) before this one. You need to show all your route definitions (in order).

Answer (score 0):

Model binding will work with GET and POST. <strike>Looks like your keyword parameter has a lowercase k. Your route definition uses uppercase K. If you fix these inconsistency it should work</strike>.

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive!